# Is there any way to get google contacts having password and username(email) without specific account settings?

Tags: java, authorization, gdata

I am trying to use gdata to get the google contacts of a specific user. The action will be performed in a console application. Having username(email) and a password I can retrieve the data I need in case on the account level access of unchecked applications is enabled (As I understand I am using ClientLogin). I also can use the application-specific password if it is set on acount level.
I know that I can use Oauth to authorize without using userId-password, but that hardly can work for me because as I understand each use will have to generate Client ID for native application inclusing CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET and REDIRECT URIS(please correct me if I am not right)

The code I am using is:

```
ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService("projectName");
contactsService.setUserCredentials(email, password);
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
Query myQuery = new Query(feedUrl);
myQuery.setMaxResults(100);
ContactFeed resultFeed = contactsService.getFeed(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);
```

Is there any way to get all contacts from the account not depending on the account settings, having userId(email) and passowrd? (Opening browser and making user to authorize or something like that may also work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working
Just in case somebody faces the same problem

Create an account in Google, generate the json file (Client ID for native application) including CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET and REDIRECT 
Place the json file into your application
Create credentials in similar way as the following

```
public class AuthorizationHelper {

    public static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
                new java.io.File("permissionsFile", "PermissionsFolder");
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("client_secrets.json")));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus "
                            + "into plus-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full")).setDataStoreFactory(
                dataStoreFactory).build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("googleAccount");
    }
}
```

where permissionsFile and permissionsFolder is file and folder where temporarily will be stored your permissions of the account you are trying to log in with
googleAccount - the account you've created(I used without @gmail.com)

Then just do

```
myService.setOAuth2Credentials(AuthorizationHelper.authorize());
```

and delete the

```
contactsService.setUserCredentials(email, password);
```

As you will not need the login and password in your code.

You will be redirected to the login page in browser and asked to enter login and passord

Hope that helps somebody

Thanks

Ievgenii